# How to load a modal on Page-Load only if user has NOT logged in

Tags: php, ajax, modal-dialog

Here is a modal plug-in that I'm going to use for a wordpress site for a user to log-in. Right now it just appears when you click on the button...I want the homepage to load the modal automatically ONLY IF the user of the page has NOT logged in yet...I appreciate the help!

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
// Load the modal window
$('a.login-window').click(function() {

    // Get the value in the href of our button.
    var login_id = $(this).attr('href');

    // Add our overlay to the body and fade it in.
    $('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);

    // Fade in the modal window.
    $(login_id).fadeIn(300);

    // center our modal window with the browsers.
    var margin_left = ($(login_id).width() + 24) / 2;
    var margin_top = ($(login_id).height() + 24) / 2;

    $(login_id).css({
        'margin-left' : -margin_left,
        'margin-top' : -margin_top
    });

    return false;
});


// Close the modal window and overlay when we click the close button or on the overlay
$('.close-btn').click(function() {
    $('#overlay, .login-popup').fadeOut('300m', function() {
        $('#overlay').remove();
    });

    return false;
});


// Display our different form fields when buttons are clicked
$('.wpml-content:not(:first)').hide();
$('.wpml-nav').click(function(e) {

    // Remove any messages that currently exist.
    $('.wpml-content > p.message').remove();

    // Get the link set in the href attribute for the currently clicked element.
    var form_field = $(this).attr('href');

    $('.wpml-content').hide();
    $('.section-container ' + form_field).fadeIn('fast');

    e.preventDefault();

    if(form_field === '#login') {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut().removeClass().addClass('hide-login');
    } else {
        $('a[href="#login"]').parent().removeClass().addClass('inline').fadeIn();
    }
});


// Run our login ajax
$('#login-box #form').on('submit', function(e) {

    // Stop the form from submitting so we can use ajax.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check what form is currently being submitted so we can return the right values for the ajax request.
    var form_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    // Remove any messages that currently exist.
    $('.wpml-content > p.message').remove();

    // Display our loading message while we check the credentials.
    $('.wpml-content > h2').after('<p class="message notice">' + wpml_script.loadingmessage + '</p>');

    // Check if we are trying to login. If so, process all the needed form fields and return a faild or success message.
    if ( form_id === 'login' ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: wpml_script.ajax,
            data: {
                'action'     : 'ajaxlogin', // Calls our wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username'   : $('#form #login_user').val(),
                'password'   : $('#form #login_pass').val(),
                'rememberme' : $('#form #rememberme').val(),
                'login'      : $('#form input[name="login"]').val(),
                'security'   : $('#form #security').val()
            },
            success: function(results) {

                // Check the returned data message. If we logged in successfully, then let our users know and remove the modal window.
                if(results.loggedin === true) {
                    $('.wpml-content > p.message').removeClass('notice').addClass('success').text(results.message).show();
                    $('#overlay, .login-popup').delay(5000).fadeOut('300m', function() {
                        $('#overlay').remove();
                    });
                    window.location.href = wpml_script.redirecturl;
                } else {
                    $('.wpml-content > p.message').removeClass('notice').addClass('error').text(results.message).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else if ( form_id === 'register' ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: wpml_script.ajax,
            data: {
                'action'   : 'ajaxlogin', // Calls our wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username' : $('#form #reg_user').val(),
                'email'    : $('#form #reg_email').val(),
                'register' : $('#form input[name="register"]').val(),
                'security' : $('#form #security').val()
            },
            success: function(results) {
                if(results.registerd === true) {
                    $('.wpml-content > p.message').removeClass('notice').addClass('success').text(results.message).show();
                    $('#register #form input:not(#user-submit)').val('');
                } else {
                    $('.wpml-content > p.message').removeClass('notice').addClass('error').text(results.message).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else if ( form_id === 'forgotten' ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: wpml_script.ajax,
            data: {
                'action'    : 'ajaxlogin', // Calls our wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username'  : $('#form #forgot_login').val(),
                'forgotten' : $('#form input[name="register"]').val(),
                'security'  : $('#form #security').val()
            },
            success: function(results) {
                if(results.reset === true) {
                    $('.wpml-content > p.message').removeClass('notice').addClass('success').text(results.message).show();
                    $('#forgotten #form input:not(#user-submit)').val('');
                } else {
                    $('.wpml-content > p.message').removeClass('notice').addClass('error').text(results.message).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if all else fails and we've hit here... something strange happen and notify the user.
        $('.wpml-content > p.message').text('Something  Please refresh your window and try again.');
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Check if they're logged in, and if not, use PHP to load the modal functions and file. If not, don't load it. PHP controls what appears on the client side.

For example, in the head section of the PHP file for the page, you could have a line that calls the script based on a variable `$logged_in` that you somehow determine the value of with sessions or whatever:

```
<?php
if ( ! $logged_in){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/javascript/mymodal.js"></script>';
}
?>
```

You could do the same for echoing the click functions, etc..